# Angular 4x label for doesn't work

Tags: angular

I am using angularjs 4.3.4 via angular CLI which is working fine. However I am getting strange issue. I had created a custom component with checkbox and label. the id and for property value comes from custom tag attribute. When I see the html code I can see that it has been generated the id and for attribute as expected. But clicking on label doesn't check or uncheck the checkbox. Here is my code:

> input.component.html (Option 1)

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <span>
        <input id="{{id}}" type="checkbox" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label for="{{id}}">{{title}}</label>
      </span>
</div>
```

> input.component.html (Option 2)

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <span>
        <input bind.id="id" type="checkbox" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label bind.for="id">{{title}}</label>
      </span>
</div>
```

> input.component.html (Option 3)

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <span>
        <input [id]="id" type="checkbox" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label [for]="id">{{title}}</label>
      </span>
</div>
```

> input.component.html (Option 4)

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <span>
        <input attr.id="id" type="checkbox" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label attr.for="id">{{title}}</label>
      </span>
</div>
```

**None of the above mentioned options are working.**

> input.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.less']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> app.component.html

```
<my-input title="Testing" id="checkBox"></my-input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of this solutions:

```
<label [attr.for]="id">{{title}}</label>
<label attr.for="{{id}}">{{title}}</label>
<label htmlFor="{{id}}">{{title}}</label>
```

with a plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/RI0bmtX1kceDdd3xt1g6?p=preview

Comment: I am not able to make it work. Here I tried on plunker but its not working at all. I do not know what am I doing wrong. https://plnkr.co/edit/QZjkT47TnKIVRaZRvSNi?p=preview

Comment: I fixed your plunker, look at it https://plnkr.co/edit/ycvUFl39KCafepYgLjOz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Vega for fixing my plunker :). However that was not the issue. I just added my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Vega Thanks for your help. I figured out what was wrong with my code for checkbox component.

In case some one else is looking for solution of same problem here is working example.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/UTXmMEW2jEE1lblnKMuK?p=preview.
```

**Requirement was make custom checkbox component with title and id property**.

**Problem**,
Above mentioned code works fine and renders checkbox with title. When you click on the title of checkbox that should check the checkbox but it didn't.

**Reason**: The **id** property in the custom input component is an html tag attribute/property even though it is a custom component and has it's own id property defined. Since **id** is an HTML attribute therefore angular ignores it and was not transferred to the custom component input property.

**Solution 1**: Change input property **id** to **myid** in the custom component

```
<my-input title="Does Work" myid="checkbox2"></my-input>
```

**Solution 2**: Pass the **id** property of custom component as one way data binding

**Correct way** *check the way i pas the id value*

```
<my-input title="Does Work" [id]="'checkbox2'"></my-input>
```

**Wrong way**

```
<my-input title="Does Work" [id]="checkbox2"></my-input>
<my-input title="Does Work" id="checkbox2"></my-input>
```

I hope that will help someone like me.

Riy